# Easier way to verify a timestamp

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a program that verifies timestamps, however as of right now it uses a Regex to verify them. What I want to know is if there is an easier way to verify a timestamp in the following format: `05/03/2016 05:34:54 AM` or `PM`.

The methods for the program look like this:

```
class TimeStampFormatError < StandardError; end

def verify_timestamp(stamp)
  begin
    if !(stamp[/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M\z/])
      puts 'Invalid format of timestamp example: 06/07/2016 5:30:23 AM'
      raise TimeStampFormatError
    else
      stamp
    end
  rescue TimeStampFormatError
    puts 'Invalid Timestamp format'
    get_timestamp
  end
end

def get_timestamp
  print 'Enter timestamp: '
  tm = gets.chomp
  verify_timestamp(tm)
end
```

Comment: You can use [DateTime.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#M000214) with the appropriate format. If it fails with `ArgumentError`, then the input date string doesn't match the specified format.

Comment: Keep in Mind, that using a regex on this will only *validate the format*. It does not check if the timestamp (i.e. 31 February) is valid at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#M000214) with the appropriate format. If it fails with `ArgumentError`, then the input date string doesn't match the specified format.

```
require 'date'

begin
  print DateTime.strptime('05/03/2016 05:34:54 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
rescue ArgumentError
  print 'not ok'
end
```

Some testing:

```
$ ruby -e "require 'date'; begin; print DateTime.strptime('05/03/2016 05:34:54 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'); rescue ArgumentError; print 'not ok'; end"
2016-03-05T05:34:54+00:00
```

Another (with a missing `M` on `AM`):

```
$ ruby -e "require 'date'; begin; print DateTime.strptime('05/03/2016 05:34:54 A', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'); rescue ArgumentError; print 'not ok'; end"
not ok
```